# How to open URL data dynamically in Webview on recyclerView item click in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, webview, android-recyclerview

In my app, I'm using recyclerView and retrofit to load the news headlines,description and image. Since I am loading it dynamically, each recyclerView adapter item loads the news headlines from different URL., I would like my user to read the detailed news on webView, when a specific adapter row item is clicked. I don't know how to implement this feature. I would like to present in such a way that consider if an recyclerView adapter item contains "News 1" from an URL with that image and if the user clicks on the adapter item, then that specific URL and with the news and image should load in the individual webView. Likewise if the user clicks any adapter item, then the URL  corresponding to the row item should get loaded seperatly in webView

Here's the sample response:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "msg": "news_list",
    "news_details": [
        {
            "title": "news title",
            "image": "",
            "description": "<img src='https://images.link.com",
            "link": "https://www.somenewslink.com/news.html",
            "view_link": "https://www.somenewslink.com/news.html",
            "provider": "NewsProvider"
        }
```

Here's my custom adapter:

```
public class FragmentOneAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FragmentOneAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

    Context context;
    Activity mActivity;
    List<NewsList> newsList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String TAG = FragmentOneAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public FragmentOneAdapter(Activity activity, List<NewsList> newsList){
        this.mActivity = activity;
        this.newsList = newsList;

    }






    @Override
    public FragmentOneAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_one, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FragmentOneAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.e(TAG, "size==>"+ newsList.size());



        holder.newsTitle.setText(newsList.get(position).title);
        holder.description_tView.setText(newsList.get(position).description);
        holder.provider_tView.setText(newsList.get(position).provider);
        try {
            if (!newsList.get(position).image.equals("")) {
                if (newsList.get(position).image != null) {


                    Picasso
                            .with(mActivity)
                            .load(newsList.get(position).image)
                            .into(holder.newsImageView);

                    holder.newsImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "_image_empty==>");
                }


            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "_image_empty==>");
                //    Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, "profile_image is Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }catch (NullPointerException e){

            Toast.makeText(context, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    @Override

    public int getItemCount(){
        return newsList.size();

    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView newsTitle;
        TextView description_tView;
        TextView provider_tView;
        ImageView newsImageView;
        LinearLayout click;




        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


            newsImageView = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsImageView);
            description_tView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_tView);
            provider_tView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.provider_tView);
            newsTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
            click = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.click);

        }
    }
}
```

And This is how I'm calling it in my Main Fragment class:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment{
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RetrofitInterface apiInterface;
    Activity activity;
    FragmentOneAdapter fragmentOneAdapter;
    public List<NewsList> newsLists;
    public static final String TAG = OneFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
        activity = getActivity();

        Initialization(view);


        return view;
    }

    public void Initialization(View view){

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(RetrofitInterface.serverUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        apiInterface = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

        GetNews();

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"This recyclerview has been clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        }

        public void GetNews(){
            Log.e(TAG, "GetNews==>");
            CommonRequest commonRequest = new CommonRequest();
            commonRequest.user_id = "1";
            commonRequest.language_id = "1";
            commonRequest.type_id = "10";
            final Call<ListDetails>newslist = apiInterface.news(commonRequest);
            newslist.enqueue(new Callback<ListDetails>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<ListDetails> call, Response<ListDetails> response) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        if (response.body().status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                            if (!response.body().news_details.isEmpty()) {
                                if (response.body().news_details != null) {
                                    newsLists = response.body().news_details;
                                    Log.e(TAG, "list_size ==>" + newsLists);
                                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
                                    fragmentOneAdapter = new FragmentOneAdapter(activity, newsLists);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(fragmentOneAdapter);
                                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                    fragmentOneAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();





                                }else {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "list_empty==>");
                                }

                            }else {
                                Log.e(TAG, "list_empty==>");
                            }
                        }else {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, response.body().msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<ListDetails> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Server Busy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                }
            });






        }






}
```

Comment: All you need is a listener that passes the url data as one of the parameters of the interface's method, and is implemented on the Fragment/Activity, where you write the code to start WebViewActivity and load the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not misunderstanding, you have a `Recycler view` for news header and a `webview` for news details?

In this case, you can tell your `webview` to load your `News URL` when item's `onClick` method is fired.

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getActivity(), recyclerView, new RecyclerTouchListener.ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view, int position) {
       // Load your URL here
       // WebView.loadURL(newsList[position].view_link) or etc



    }

    @Override
    public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

    }
));
```

In case you want to load in a new page, just push the url through `Bundle` to a new `Activity` / `Fragment` with WebView and display it.

Comment: ., My doubt is what's  that Load your URL here you've mentioned means? There's not just single URL. there're around 6 to 8 URLs.. that's why I am asking you

Comment: The user is tapping one item each time, and each item is presenting a news, so i guess you would like to load the details URL for that news. The `position` in `onClick` will tell you the position of item user is tapping
Correct me if i misunderstood your flow.

Comment: ., thanks,, finally I fixed this nd got my requirement